# Find a line in an .ics file using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to store certain lines from an .ics file to separate strings depending on their contents. I've been able to convert an .ics file to a string, but I am having difficulty searching it line by line to find certain keywords.

The string (and file) contains:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//School of Rochester NY |-ECPv4.8.1//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:School of Rochester NY |
```

I've been able to display the text in the logcat, but I have not been able to save the lines as separate strings.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        val file_name = "education-1e1a4bdab8e.ics"
        val ics_string = application.assets.open(file_name).bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }

        Log.i("TAG", ics_string)

        textView.text = ics_string

        if (ics_string.contains("BEGIN:VCALENDAR", ignoreCase = true))
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "contains event")
        }


    }
```

The logcat confirms that the text is in the document, but not which line.
Is there any way to add lines of a text as separate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) you have already 4 functions that all give you the lines.

1. [`readLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/read-lines.html) gives you a `List<String>` containing all the lines
2. [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/use-lines.html) lets you use a sequence of lines which you can then transform and assures that after calling it, the reader is closed
3. [`lineSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-buffered-reader/line-sequence.html) returns a sequence of the lines, but does not close the reader after calling it
4. [`lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) returns a `Stream<String>` containing the lines and basically comes from the `BufferedReader` itself. As you are using Kotlin you probably do not want to use this method.
5. [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/use-lines.html) and [`readLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html) are also available on [`File`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/index.html) itself

As I am not sure what you really want to accomplish I recommend you start with `readLines` directly. The `ics`-file is usually rather small and with the lines you can still filter/map whatever you want. The next best candidate then is probably either `useLines` or `lineSequence`. It really depends on what you do next.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension function on `String`, `lines()`, something like this:

```
fun lines() {
    val text = """BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//School of Rochester NY |-ECPv4.8.1//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:School of Rochester NY |"""

    val foundLines = text.lines().map {
        it.contains("BEGIN:VCALENDAR") to it
    }.filter { (contains, _) -> contains }
     .map { it.second }

    println(foundLines)
}

fun main() {
    lines()
}
```

Comment: you can spare your `map`/`filter`/`map`: `text.lines().filter { it.contains("BEGIN:VCALENDAR") }`. Note also that you created intermediate lists on each `filter` and `map` which you basically didn't want in the first place...